# How to disable unwanted device log in ddms logcat

Tags: android, android-logcat

My problem is that : when i connect my Android device to eclipse then in ddms unwanted device log is print continuously so that after some time my application log is disappear from the log cat .
How can i disable the device log and show only application log.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can add a filter to the logs you _want_, so it only shows those and even then, you have to do it per session. Can't disable logs permanently afaik.

Comment: @Shyam Next time in comment for edit you should put tag edit, not formatting.

Answer (score 1):

Look at this image here.You just need to double click your package in logcat and this dialog opens.Now you can decide if you want only  *error log*  or *verbose log* or *info log*,etc.
Just select the level of log and you will then recieve only that type of logs only..!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

add a filter on the top field of your logcat like app:. you can also filter by tag (tag: or even by anything you want to find within the messages (just type a phrase you want o filter by). There are also pid: that corresponds to process id (its helpful when youre filtering app which is already released / not in debug mode as theres no application tag visible)